# JMeter Header issues with Cookied/Headrs

Tags: cookies, jmeter, httprequest, fiddler, blazemeter

I have a test I need to perform on a website which includes several pages transitions.
At first I used the add on tool BlazeMeter to capture the traffic from my chrome browser, added the results to JMeter and ran the test plan, and it failed.
For comparison and attempt to diagnoze the problem, I opened Fiddler and did the same flow again, added the .jml file to JMeter, and compared the Headers of the request to the captured data and I noticed that there are differences between the request, in the request headers:[image: Image from Fiddler]

The JMeter Header:
[image: Jmeter header]

So, question is, is there an issue with the cookies? My cookie manager in JMeter doesn't have any values.
Should I concatenate cookie properties in my JMeter flow? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, JMeter is smart enough to handle cookies automatically. You will be able to see the values in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

The inputs in the HTTP Cookie Manager allow you to set your custom **User Defined** cookies if required:

[image: Cookie Manager user defined cookies]

[image: Cookie Manager in Work]

All cookies which are being provided via [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header will be handled by JMeter.

---

Given you are load testing an ASP.NET application I would recommend getting familiarized with [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide as the chance you will be able to successfully replay recorded scenario is minimal.